# How can I run Kotlin-Script (*.kts) files from within Gradle?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

How can I run Kotlin-Script (*.kts) files from within Gradle?

From the command line, I can call:
kotlinc -script foo.kts

How can I do this from gradle (build.gradle)?

Comment: Both current answers to this question miss the point completely. The question is about executing .kts scripts from within gradle. Both answers are about authoring a gradle build using kotlin format.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76505455/4161471

Answer (score -1):

You have two options here to run a gradle build file named `build.gradle.kts`.

1. Change the name of your build file in `settings.gradle` to `build.gradle.kts`:
   `rootProject.buildFileName = 'build.gradle.kts'` and run `gradle <tasknames>`.
2. Run `gradle -b build.gradle.kts <tasknames>`.

Answer (score -2):

Note that with version gradle 4.21 (current at the time of writing this), you do not need any "buildFileName" entry, or any other entry in `settings.gradle`.  If there is a `build.gradle.kts` and no `build.gradle`, `gradle` will use `build.gradle.kts` by default.

However having the setting for `buildFileName` does allow `build.gradle` to be ignored. Without the setting, you have to remove (or rename) `build.gradle` in order to run build.gradle.kts.

If you have both a `build.gradle` and a `build.gradle.kts` you can switch between the two by commenting and un-commenting the `buildFileName` setting.