# Is there a way to instantinate KTS script engine in the Gradle KTS?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-script

I want to use 3d party library in my project build process.
Library methods requires ScriptEngine. When I'm trying to instantiate it i got an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to construct script definition: Unable to load base class kotlin.script.experimental.api.KotlinType@42842bb8
    at kotlin.script.experimental.host.ConfigurationFromTemplateKt.getTemplateClass(configurationFromTemplate.kt:189)
    at kotlin.script.experimental.host.ConfigurationFromTemplateKt.createScriptDefinitionFromTemplate(configurationFromTemplate.kt:36)
    at kotlin.script.experimental.jsr223.KotlinJsr223DefaultScriptEngineFactory.<init>(KotlinJsr223DefaultScriptEngineFactory.kt:74)
    at ce.domain.usecase.load.LoadMetaFilesForTargetUseCase.invoke(LoadMetaFilesUseCase.kt:17)
    at ce.domain.usecase.entry.BuildProjectUseCase.invoke(BuildProjectUseCase.kt:24)
    at ce.domain.usecase.entry.BuildProjectUseCase.invoke$default(BuildProjectUseCase.kt:18)
    at Build_gradle$$$result$1.invoke(build.gradle.kts:68)
    at Build_gradle$$$result$1.invoke(build.gradle.kts:60)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.ProjectExtensionsKt$sam$org_gradle_api_Action$0.execute(ProjectExtensions.kt)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:368)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.ProjectExtensionsKt.task(ProjectExtensions.kt:147)
    at Build_gradle.<init>(build.gradle.kts:60)
    ...
```

I've reproduced issue with simple grdale project:
Sample project gradle:

```
import kotlin.script.experimental.jsr223.KotlinJsr223DefaultScriptEngineFactory

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.21"
    application
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jsr223:1.8.10")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-common:1.8.10")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.8.10")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

abstract class TestProjectTask : DefaultTask() {
    @get: InputFile
    abstract val projectFile: RegularFileProperty

    @TaskAction
    fun execute() {
        try {
            val eng2 = KotlinJsr223DefaultScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine()
            println("Project file = ${projectFile.get()} $eng2")
            val worker = Worker()
            worker.doWork(eng2, projectFile.asFile.get().absolutePath)
        } catch (err: Throwable) {
            err.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

task("hello2", TestProjectTask::class) {
    projectFile.set(File("./project.kts"))
}
```

KotlinJsr223DefaultScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine() always throws same exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to work done by contributors in [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-53707/The-Kotlin-Gradle-plugin-should-allow-to-wrap-a-Kotlin-script-inside-a-Gradle-task) and the [linked comment thread](https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/494785/Is-there-some-Gradle-plugin-to-let-a-main-kts-script-run-Esp), the answer is relative simple, even if discovering how to do it was not! I've cleaned up the provided workaround.

Summary:

- Create a Gradle task for running the Kotlin script
- fetch the required compilation and runtime dependencies
- Run `K2JVMCompiler` to generate the sources

I recommend using a [buildSrc convention plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html) to set up the requisite logic. It helps keep the build scripts cleaner and more declarative, and setup-logic is contained within buildSrc.

#### Kotlin dependencies

First, make sure that the `K2JVMCompiler` class is available.

If you're working in a single `build.gradle.kts`, then this can be achieved by applying the Kotlin plugin:

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.22"
}
```

Or if writing a plugin/pre-compiled script plugin, add a dependency on the Kotlin Gradle Plugin in the project's `build.gradle.kts`.

A compile-time dependency on `kotlin-compiler-embeddable` is required for accessing the `K2JVMCompiler` class.

```kotlin
// buildSrc/build.gradle.kts
plugins {
  `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.22")

  // required for K2JVMCompiler::class - will be provided at runtime by Gradle
  compileOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.8.22")
}
```

> ⚠️ Note that adding a dependency on KGP in `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` means that *all* other KGP versions must be removed.
>
> ```kotlin
> // build.gradle.kts
> plugins {
>   kotlin("jvm") // no version needed - it's set in buildSrc/build.gradle.kts
> }
> ```

#### Run task

Next, let's create the task that will be used to run the `.main.kts` files.

In order to run a Kotlin script, we need a few things:

- the location of the Kotlin script (obviously!)
- the classpath used to *compile* the Kotlin script
- the classpath used to *run* the Kotlin script

In order to follow Gradle best practices, tracking [task's input and output files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/incremental_build.html#sec:task_inputs_outputs) is also important (but is not strictly required).

```kotlin
// buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/RunKotlinScript.kt

import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.file.ConfigurableFileCollection
import org.gradle.api.file.RegularFileProperty
import org.gradle.api.tasks.*
import org.gradle.process.ExecOperations
import javax.inject.Inject

/** Task for running Kotlin Scripts */
abstract class RunKotlinScript @Inject constructor(
    private val executor: ExecOperations
) : DefaultTask() {
    /** Location of the `.kts` file (required) */
    @get:InputFile
    abstract val script: RegularFileProperty

    /** (optional) Files that the script uses as an input */
    @get:InputFiles
    @get:Optional
    abstract val scriptInputs: ConfigurableFileCollection

    /** (optional) Files that the script produces as output */
    @get:OutputFiles
    abstract val scriptOutputs: ConfigurableFileCollection

    @get:Classpath
    abstract val compileClasspath: ConfigurableFileCollection

    @get:Classpath
    abstract val runtimeClasspath: ConfigurableFileCollection

    init {
        group = "run kts"
        description = "Runs a Kotlin script"
    }

    @TaskAction
    fun run() {
        val scriptPath = script.get().asFile.invariantSeparatorsPath
        val runtimeClasspath = runtimeClasspath.asPath

        executor.javaexec {
            classpath(compileClasspath)
            mainClass.set(org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler::class.qualifiedName)
            args(
                "-no-stdlib",
                "-no-reflect",
                "-classpath", runtimeClasspath,
                "-script", scriptPath,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

(As previously mentioned, it's best to do this in a buildSrc directory, but you can paste this task into a regular `build.gradle.kts` too.)

#### Compile and Runtime dependencies

Let's use a [pre-compiled convention plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins) to define how to fetch the dependencies needed to compile and run a Kotlin script.

```
// buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/kotlin-script-runner.gradle.kts

plugins {
  kotlin("jvm") // no version needed - it's set in buildSrc/build.gradle.kts
}

// Fetch dependencies necessary to compile and run kts scripts inside Gradle,
// so installing the kotlin CLI is not required (e.g. on CI/CD, or Heroku)
val ktsCompileClasspath by configurations.creating<Configuration> {
    description = "Dependencies used to compile Kotlin scripts"
    isCanBeConsumed = false
}

val ktsRuntimeClasspath by configurations.creating<Configuration> {
    description = "Dependencies used to run Kotlin scripts"
    isCanBeConsumed = false
    // only fetch direct dependencies - the scripting context will pull in other dependencies
    isTransitive = false
}

dependencies {
    // add compile-time dependencies on the regular and scripting Kotlin compilers
    ktsCompileClasspath(kotlin("compiler"))
    ktsCompileClasspath(kotlin("scripting-compiler"))
    // only depend on Kotlin main-kts for runtime
    ktsRuntimeClasspath(kotlin("main-kts"))
}
```

We now have two [Configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/dependency_management_terminology.html#sub:terminology_configuration) that contain the requisite dependencies. In the same convention plugin, let's add those dependencies to *all* RunKotlinScript tasks.

```
// buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/kotlin-script-runner.gradle.kts

// ...

tasks.withType<RunKotlinScript>().configureEach {
    runtimeClasspath.from(ktsRuntimeClasspath)
    compileClasspath.from(ktsCompileClasspath)
}
```

#### Creating run tasks

This convention plugin can be applied to any script in the project:

```kotlin
// my-subproject/build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  `kotlin-script-runner`
}
```

and then you can create a task, which will be correctly configured

```kotlin
// my-subproject/build.gradle.kts


tasks.register<RunKotlinScript>("runDoSomethingKts") {
    script.set(file("scripts/do-something.main.kts"))
    scriptOutputs.from("scripts/out.txt")    
    scriptInputs.from("script/input.txt")
}
```

and can be run, using Gradle

```bash
./gradlew runDoSomethingKts
```